# Access property chain as string

Tags: javascript

I'm building a JS metadata generator so we have access to strongtyped entities and properties. I do this by generating a `Metadata` prototype and adding a `Entities` prototype into it. I then populate that prototype with all of our entities such as `Metadata.Entities._Customer` which returns `'Customer'` as a string and `Metadata.Entities.Customer` which lists all of its properties.

However the issue becomes when you have nested properties like `entity.entityRef.property`. What I want to call is `Metadata.Entities.Customer.Category.Description` and have it return `'Category.Description'`.

If possible I want to avoid generating every possible route since our metadata can get very extensive, so I was hoping to know if javascript is capable of fishing out the last bit without having to give it as a string literal (it kinda voids the purpose of wanting to make it more strongtyped) in which case I can simply have `Metadata.Entities.Customer.Category` point to `Metadata.Entities.Category` to access its properties.

```
var Metadata= { 
    Entities: {}
};
Metadata.Entities._Customer = 'Customer';
Metadata.Entities._Category = 'Category';
Metadata.Entities.Customer = {};
Metadata.Entities.Category = {};
Metadata.Entities.Customer.Category = Metadata.Entities.Category;
Metadata.Entities.Cateogry.Description = 'Description';
```

Comment: Can you create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've added a snippet of the generated metadata and cleaned it to be more human readable. Not entirely sure how it will help

Comment: I think what we're after is *how it's generated*.

Comment: It's custom generated in C# (through a webapi call) based on metadata of the datacontext there. Returned as a string and then manually inserted into a JS file by myself.

Comment: The generated javascript is as you see above (except no spaces and linebreaks)

Comment: What you want makes no sense at all. After `Metadata.Entities.Customer.Category = Metadata.Entities.Category`, these values are **identical**.